# Symfony - set form value on save

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

A quick question. I have a symfony form. When I save the form, I want my created_by field to be set automatically on save.

So, I'm passing the current user id as an option in the form:

```
$this->form = new ContractForm(null,array("created_by"=>$this->getUser()->getId()));
```

And in the configure method of the form class I have:

```
$this->setDefault('created_by', $this->getOption("created_by"));
```

If I had a created_by widget and set it to hidden, this would work great, however, I don't want to have a field displayed as a user could easily manipulate using firebug or other tools alike.

So my question to you, how do I save a column value if the field does not exist as a widget?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont need to have a widget for this, just in the configure method of your form call.

```
<?php
$this->getObject()->setCreatedBy($this->getOption('created_by'));
?>
```

There really is no need to overwrite a method.

Also for this to work youd have to initiate your form like this

```
<?php
$this->form = new ContractForm(new Contract(), array('created_by' => $this->getUser()->getId()));`
?>
```

Comment: Hey, Henrik, this is exactly what I did in the end. Thanks for the reply :-)

Answer (score 0):

Or in your ContractForm class you can add to configure()

```
$this->widgetSchema['created_by'] = new sfWidgetFormInputText(array('default' => $this->getUser()->getId()));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can use this behaviour on your class [sfDoctrineActAsSignablePlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfDoctrineActAsSignablePlugin).